# codeigniter project configuration on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter project work properly on localhost but when i transfer it on hosting sever then its default_controller in route.php  i.e login work properly but after login it is showing "The resource you are looking 
for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
My config.php file changes:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://XXXXXXXX ';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When you manually invoke any other controller and method via URL does that work?

Comment: Could you add the URL that shows up after you login? The one the error is showed for.

Comment: try `$config['base_url'] = 'http://XXXXXXXX/';` add slash at the end

Comment: http://XXXXXXX.net/login/admin_login

Comment: still not working.when i enter link manually still its not working

Comment: on local every thing is working fine but on live server http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net its not working default login page open at url http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net after login to page its showing "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."    at url http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/login/admin_login